# UnitOfWork / working with multiple databases in a DDD application

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

We have an application which stores its data in two different databases. At some point in the future we may only be storing our data in one database, so we want it to be as painful as possible to make this kind of change. For this reason, we wrap our DbContexts in a single MyDataContext which gets injected into our UnitOfWork and Repository classes.

```
class MyDataContext : IDataContext {
    internal Database1Context Database1;
    internal Database2Context Database2;
}

class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {
    MyDataContext myDataContext;

    public UnitOfWork(MyDataContext myDataContext) {
        this.myDataContext = myDataContext;
    }

    public Save() {
        //todo: add transaction/commit/rollback logic
        this.myDataContext.Database1.SaveChanges();
        this.myDataContext.Database2.SaveChanges();
    }
}

class Database1Context : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

class Database2Context : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Customers> CustomerProfile { get; set; }
}

class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository {
    MyDataContext myDataContext;

    public CustomerRepository(MyDataContext myDataContext) {
        this.myDataContext = myDataContext;
    }

    public GetCustomerById(int id) {
        return this.myDataContext.Database1.Customers.Single(...);
    }
}
```

My first question is, am I doing it right? I've been doing a lot of reading, but admittedly DDD is a little bit overwhelming at this point.

My second question is which layer of the application do the IUnitOfWork and IDataContext interfaces reside in? I know that the interfaces for repositories live in the Core/Domain layer/assembly of the application, but not sure about these two. Should these two even have interfaces?

Comment: `so we want it to be as painful as possible to make this kind of change`. omg. you are naughty, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is, am I doing it right?

You can do that, but first reconsider why you're storing data in different places in the first place. Are distinct aggregates at play? Furthermore, if you wish to commit changes to two different databases within a transaction, you will need to use 2-phase commit which is best to avoid. If you have different aggregates, perhaps you can save them separately?

> My second question is which layer of the application do the
>   IUnitOfWork and IDataContext interfaces reside in?

These can be placed in the application layer.